# Forward declaration issue

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have a <strike>cyclical redundancy</strike> circular dependency between two classes in my project, `StatusEffect` and `BaseCharacter`.

Both classes need to be aware of each other as the `BaseCharacter` needs to store a set of `StatusEffect`s and `StatusEffect` needs to be able to do operations on `BaseCharacter`. I don't think it's possible to eliminate this behavior and still have it work correctly. Here's what I'm trying to do right now:

Base Character exists inside the namespace `Game::Character` and `StatusEffect` exists inside the namespace `Game::StatusEffects`

inside StatusEffects.h, I forward declared `BaseCharacter` like so:

```
namespace Game {
    namespace Character {
        class BaseCharacter;
    }
}
```

then below it I have:

```
namespace Game
{   
    namespace StatusEffects
    {
        class StatusEffect
        {
        public:
            virtual void TickCharacter(Game::Character::BaseCharacter* character, int ticks = 1)
            {
                std::cout << "Name " << character->GetName() << std::endl;
            }
        protected:
        private:
            std::string name;
            int StatusEffectUID;
        };
    }
}
```

However, this is giving me a compiler error:

> Error 1   error C2027: use of undefined type 'Game::Character::BaseCharacter'

I thought that because I'm using a pointer, this forward declaration is fine. Is there something else I need to forward declare? I dont need to forward declare the whole class definition do I?

Comment: When you say "cyclical redundancy", do you really mean "circular dependency"?

Comment: ah yea... not sure why i put cyclical redundancy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't call a method through a pointer to a forward-declared class. You have to move this code somewhere where the class is already defined - for example into a .cpp file that includes both classes definition.

Comment: Why do you want this virtual method defined in the header anyway?

Comment: @inflagranti: Sometimes a call to a virtual method might be non-virtual.

Comment: I'm aware of that, however, I wanted to check if those specific conditions apply in this case; and also of the code is 'hot' enough to warrant putting code in the header for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Your forward `declaration` is fine.  However, you must not refer to any of the members of such a class.

You should only declare the TickCharacter method in the header.  You should then `define` the `StatusEffect::TickCharacter` method in its own module file after `#include` ing the header file which contains the full declaration of `BaseCharacter`.